# wordpress referring to own site not possible

Tags: html, wordpress

On the wordpress site i'm building a want a link that refers to a section on the same page.

Code here:

```
<a href="#offer" target="_self">test</a>
```

The code on the landing section here:

```
<a name="offer"></a>
```

Somehow the link is ignored. Maybe it has to do with the wordpress setup? Here the site: http://bbwebdes.myhostpoint.ch/webauftritt/

I've tried everything with relative and absolute links but nothing is working and I have no clue why.

Comment: The old way of using named anchors used the name attribute, but the new way uses IDs. Try `<a id="offer"></a>`

Comment: Now it works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You need it to be an ID if you're referencing an internal link

```
<a id="offer"></a>
```

Also might I suggest using a DIV or a SPAN instead of using a link, since it could lead to horrible outcomes.

```
<span id="offer"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two mistakes.

You should use `id` instead of `name`.

and you should use `div` or `span` instead of `a`.

Try this:

```
<div id="offer"></div>
//<a id="offer"></a> --> Dont use this
```